# Is replacing a particular line in a file through a bash script possible in VIM or EX?

Tags: bash, vim, vi, ex

I would like to modify a particular line, say line 5, in a file by using the `EOEX` construct how can I achieve my aim? The code snippet that I use to achieve my purpose is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
S=0.030
F=0.150
N=30
DIFF=`echo "scale=3; $F - $S" | bc -l`
dw=`echo "scale=3; $DIFF / $N" | bc -l`
is=`echo "scale=3; $S / $dw" | bc -l`
if=`echo "scale=3; $F / $dw" | bc -l`
ex ~/Desktop/Dropbox/MATLAB/FFT.m  <<EOEX
  :5s/for*/for i = $S:$dw:$F/g
  :x
EOEX
```

I did some researh and learned that usually `EOF`(end of file) is used in `here scripts`  for `I/O` redirection to the standard input of a particular command(in my case it is `ex`).  I also learned that as long as the starting and finishing keywords are the same any word can be used instead of the `EOF`. My problem is that instead of the desired effect which is replacing the line with another `for loop` initializer in `Matlab` this script does not delete the line and append the string at the end of the fifth line. For reference purposes I have also added my FFT.m file. I apologize for the inconvenience caused by the abstractedness of my question previously. Note that I am also open to using another program to achieve the desired effect but curious about why it cannot be achieved in `ex` or `vim`. Please click [here](http://pastebin.com/9rqY0V7D) for the Matlab script.

Comment: If you work in VIM is much easy to do task via vim's macro or substitution commands. In any way you can invoke any bash command by twice `!` on edited line in normal mode.

Comment: What's wrong with using `sed`?

Comment: what bash script? What does vim have to do with it? What exactly is the EOEX construct? Please edit your question and explain what tools you are using and what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @terdon EOEX is just an acronym commonly used in here files for `ex` scripts instead of EOF. It apparently stands for 'end of ex' instead of 'end of file'. Not sure the OP really knows though...

Comment: @terdon I edited my question you may wish to take another look.

Comment: Wow, you most certainly did! Thanks and +1.

Comment: @terdon You are welcome, by the way do you have any idea why does it not delete the line starting from for and replace it with the second string between the slashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change line 5 of a file called `test_file` to 'hello world' using `ex` and the `EOEX` construct (by which I presume that what you mean is a 'here document'):

```
ex test_file << EOEX
5c
hello world
.
wq
EOEX
```

The above is also possible with `ed`, although note that POSIX `ed` doesn't support the `wq` command. Instead put the `w` and `q` on separate lines.

Using `sed` (a version that supports the `-i` option) is a bit simpler:

```
sed -i '15 c hello world' test_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative post yes I did mean `here document`  by `EOEX` construct I was unfamiliar with terminology sorry before, sorry about that.

Comment: By the way does the `.` switch ex between insert and command mode?

Comment: Actually I was not able to pass the shell variable values and the exact string I wanted to the ex editor.

Comment: @Vesnog, no idea why the chose `.` to leave the insert mode. You are probably best posting a separate question about your shell variables and explaining what has gone wrong in detail there.

Comment: @Graeme EDIT: The `here document` does not work when the lines following the output redirection are indented. Is this expected?

Comment: @Graeme You can see my comment above the issue is resolved but I wonder if this is always the case. You can see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document about appending a minus sign in front of `<<` to ignore the leading tabs.

Comment: @Vesnog, yup, you can use `<<-` to make `bash` strip leading white space and have a nicely indented here file.

Comment: @Graeme One more question: How can I determine if the `ex` program is operating in `POSIX` mode? I read the Wikipedia entry about it, but it is still an ambiguous concept for me. Does each program has a `POSIX` version or `POSIX` operation mode specified by environmental variables?